# Can pandas in a python script be used with nodejs

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to call use a python script with NodeJS and it will work with a python 'hello world' script, but I can't get the python script to execute when the script employs pandas.

numpy==1.15.1
pandas==0.23.4

nodeJS

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const filePath = 'python/testing2.py' 
  const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
  const pythonProcess = spawn('python3',[filePath, '-l']); 

  util.log('readingin')
  pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => { 
    const textChunk = data.toString('utf8');// buffer to string
    util.log(textChunk);
    res.json({'working': true, 'data': textChunk})
  });
});
```

python:

```
import sys 
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import datetime    

def parser(x):
    return datetime.strptime('190'+x, '%Y-%m')    

print("Output from Python") 
series = read_csv('shampoo-sales.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser=parser)
print (series)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

if i run the python script by itself:

```
$ python3 testing2.py
Output from Python
Month
1901-01-01    266.0
1901-02-01    145.9
1901-03-01    183.1
1901-04-01    119.3...

$ pip3 freeze
matplotlib==2.2.3
numpy==1.15.1
pandas==0.23.4
```

Comment: Is pandas installed for `python3`?

Comment: yeah did it work for you?

Comment: Are you sure that the `python3` that Node is finding is the same `python3` that bash finds? What is the output if you spawn instead `which python3`? Or change your script to be only `import sys print(sys.executable)`?

Comment: Thanks, I was using /usr/local/bin/python3 rather the one from my venv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check that commands you run from other processes are using the same executable of Python that you expect. Common ways to do this are

```
which python3
```

or

```
where python3
```

from your shell, or

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

in your Python script.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using the PythonShell run method using the python-shell npm package:

You will need to provide Python Shell with the options that points the pythonPath to the path in your virtualenv:

```
  var options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonPath: '/Users/WC/anaconda/envs/testtoday/bin/python',
    pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
    scriptPath: '/Volumes/Transcend/NodeJSTest/PythonNodeJS',
    args:
    [
      req.query.funds, // starting funds
      req.query.size, // (initial) wager size
      req.query.count, // wager count - number of wagers per sim
      req.query.sims // number of simulations
    ]
  }

  ps.PythonShell.run('./d_alembert.py', options, function (err, data) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    res.send(data.toString());
  });
```

To find the path of the virtualenv, activate it:

```
source activate testtoday
```

then type in:

```
which python
```

All your imports that you would have in your virtualenv becomes available for you to use in your script.